# Dropping duplicates in a dataframe row whilst keeping first occurence in sequence

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, trading

working on a side project with Pandas and trying to backtest an automated trading strategy. I've come into a slight problem where buy and sell signals are being generated and often there are a few buy singals in a row or a few sell signals in a row, as you can see from the image provided. Does anyone know how I can filter out the duplicates whilst still keeping the original buy and sell signals in tact and in line with the index? I would like a buy signal to only be proceeded with a sell instead of having it repeated a few times. Is there a way to drop the repeated signals and replace them with null values? perhaps a function has to be written which reads through the entire column and replaces the duplicates becuase the df.drop_duplicates() function does not work.

Hope to hear back from anyone, Cheers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axd40.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to keep only 1st buy/sell signal in the sequence of duplicate action, right? For example, if the value in column are `buy, buy, buy, sell, sell, buy, sell, buy, buy, sell, sell`, your desired output are `buy, sell, buy, sell, buy, sell`

If I understand you correctly, here is answer for your question.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    'action': ['b','b','s','b','s','s','b']
})
df = df.sort_values('date')
df['lag_action'] = df['action'].shift(1)
df = df[df['action'] != df['lag_action']]
df = df.drop('lag_action', axis=1)
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

**Results:**

| date | action |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | b |
| 3 | s |
| 4 | b |
| 5 | s |
| 7 | b |